# use an array to pass values into a TIMER IN SWIFT

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, nstimer

I have a working countdown which you can increase by pushing the add button and thats what the time counts down from (so basically a user can set the countdown)

I would like to display the starting time as 00:00 as it does in my label.

When I click button to increase the countdown it just begins at 1 obviously because at the moment its just an Int

can I create an array and increase the individual indexes, then display them within my label?

can anyone help with this or point me in the write code direction from what I have below
thanks

```
var timeArray: [Double : Double] =  [00, 00]


var timer = NSTimer()
var countdown = 0

func runTimer() {


timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, 

   selector:Selector("updateTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

 func updateTimer() {

  if countdown > 0 {

     countdown--
      TimerLabel.text = String(countdown)

    } else {

       countdown = 0
         TimerLabel.text = String(countdown)

  }

}

@IBOutlet weak var TimerLabel: UILabel!


@IBAction func IncreaseCountdown(sender: AnyObject) {

countdown++
TimerLabel.text = String(countdown)


}


@IBAction func StartCountdown(sender: AnyObject) {

 runTimer()

}


@IBAction func StopCountdown(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()

}




override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
   super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for `timeArray` is creating a `Dictionary` and not an `Array`.  I also suggest you use `Int` instead of `Double`:

```
var timeArray:[Int] = [0, 0]
```

To create the label for your text field:

```
// This format will create a string with 2 digits for minute and second with
// a leading 0 for each if needed like "00:00"
TimerLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", timeArray[0], timeArray[1])
```

When you create your timer, convert your time array back into a simple countdown:

```
let countdown = timeArray[0] * 60 + timeArray[1]
```

---

An entirely different approach which would work would to be just to store your time as integer seconds internally and just to display it as minutes and seconds.

```
let countdown = 100 // 1 minute, 40 seconds
TimerLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", countdown/60, countdown%60)
```